# Validation is not working in overlay

Tags: jquery, forms, overlay

This validation works and the form is submitting when form is in the main or body container .. if I put the form in CSS overlay validation is not working and form is not submitting.

**Please check this DEMO: http://www.edigitaldreams.com/testing/**

Please click the contact box and see the form .. not working ... but the same form if i put it under main page it is working without error... can anyone please help me...

Comment: your form validation working on email field, then what you want to do..?

Comment: onsubmit form needs validation and form needs to be submitted...right now not validating correctly

Comment: in your form only email validation working, for name and message there is no validation. Second thing you are not using any button inside form to submit data or any button click event. Third, kindly correct your html code for name and email (remove value or write in correct way).

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/cFQDQ/

Comment: Or also you can check : http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/at2CY/

Comment: 1. **http://www.edigitaldreams.com/testing/index1.html** 2.**http://www.edigitaldreams.com/testing/index.html** see the both url ... main page validation is working fine ... please see the overlay form ...

Comment: only vaildation is working after that form is not submitting '$('#form form').submit(function(){ $.get('data.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){ $('#content').html(data); });  return false; });'

Comment: Check my updated answer. It will surely helps you.

Comment: Have you tried my updated solution?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why your Jquery validation not working in overlay. I have one solution for 
you use simple Jquery validation here. To validate two fields no need to add one JS here.

HTML:-

```
 <label id="error_email"></label>
    <label id="error_message"></label>
    <form method="post" action="" id="contact_form" name="contact_form">
        <div class="clr">
            <div class="clr">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value="" name="name" class="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" value="" name="email" id="email" class="">
            </div>
            <div class="clr">
                <textarea placeholder="Message" id="message" rows="" cols="" name="message" style="width: 591px; height: 79px;" class="valid"></textarea>
                <div id="send">
                    <div class="send_button">   <span class="entypo mail"><i></i></span>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="send">Send</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Jquery :-

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#send').click(function () {
        $("[id^='error_']").removeClass('error');
        $("[id^='error_']").html('');
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var message = $('#message').val();
        var validate_flag = 0;
        var pattern = /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i

        if (email == '') {
            $('#error_email').addClass('error');
            $('#error_email').html('Please enter email.');
            validate_flag = 1;
        } else {
            if (!pattern.test(email)) {
                $('#error_email').addClass('error');
                $('#error_email').html('Please enter valid email.');
                validate_flag = 1;
            } 
        }

        if (message == '') {
            $('#error_message').addClass('error');
            $('#error_message').html('Please enter message content.');
            validate_flag = 1;
        }
        if (validate_flag == 0) {
                  $('#contact_form').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Css :-

```
.error{color :red;}
```

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/roopendra/3ccHG/19/

Comment: 1.**edigitaldreams.com/testing/index1.html** 2.**edigitaldreams.com/testing/index.html** see the both url ... main page validation is working fine ... please see the overlay form from contact box... please help me  –

Comment: Sure , suresh I will help you. let me check .

Comment: remove your form validation jquery and jquery.validate.js and try this http://jsfiddle.net/roopendra/3ccHG/14/. it should be better remove one js file to validate two form fields. if it will work plz let me know

Comment: only vaildation is working after that form is not submitting  '$('#form form').submit(function(){
   $.get('data.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
    $('#content').html(data);
   });    
   return false;
  });'